# How to distribute Application which has multiple class Libraries

Tags: java

I am new to JAVA (Actually migrated to JAVA from C#) and creating a Application on NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 which contains following

1. Server Application (Java Application) <-- This contain my MainClass
2. Network Layer (Java Class Library)
3. Data Access Layer (Java Class Library)

I have successfully reference the .jar in each above layers by adding jar files Project Library in NetBeans as shown in below image

[image]

When i click on build in NetBeans it creates 'dist' folder under Server Application folder which contain Server_Application.jar and a 'lib' folder which contain Network_Layer.jar

I want to ask that did I reference it correctly ?

How to distribute these file ? Should i distribute all the .jar file (Data_Access_Layer.jar, Network_Layer.jar and Server_Application.jar) ? OR just distribute the 'dist' folder of Server Application.

I also want ask that if i convert Network_Layer.jar and Data_Access_Layer.jar to '.dll' and Server_Application.jar to '.exe' file will it work correctly ?

In C# same things creates .dll files and if i want to distribute it I simply make setup of these dll and exe files. How to do same thing in JAVA using NetBeans

(I don't want to wrap all .jar files into one)